# How to assign values to any one or two prop using linq c# or inside generic method?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

```
public class Company
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int Address{ get; set; }

}

List<Company> listofCompany = new List<Company>();
```

`listofCompany` is already filled and having some data.I want to replace its `id` and `Name` using linq

I can able to do it using foreach like below

```
 foreach (var item in listofCompany )
                        {
                            item.id= 123;
                            item.Name= 999;
                        }
```

But is there any better way to do it without foreach because my foreach code is there inside other method which is a generic method like below -

```
MyData<T>(List<T> anylist){}
```

Comment: LINQ is meant for _querying_. Mutating an existing list isn't something it's especially great at.

Comment: then what is the best thing i can do ? pls suggest

Comment: I don't understand the motivation for this.  The `foreach` is just fine...

Comment: want to replace value within MyData or outside it. is my goal.

Comment: what is you purpose of not using foreach, and linq instead? If it's just to have one line of code, you could use the foreach of the list and put there a lamda: listofCompany.ForEach(x => { x.id = 123; x.Name = 999; });

Comment: got you nothing specific with linq but i was not able to understand how to do use foreach within method MyData<T>(List<T> listofCompany ){} as its generic list so thats why ask for linq solution

Comment: If you want to access specific properties of the items, then it doesn't sound like a great candidate for generics (unless you have an interface that defines these properties, in which case you can constrain `where T : IMyInterface`

Comment: ok make sense thanks for valuable inputs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're alright with generating new `Company` objects then you can use `Select` along with `ToList`.

```
listofCompany.Select(x => new Company 
               {  Id = 123, 
                  Name = 999, 
                  Address = x.Address
               }).ToList();
```

Otherwise, if you want to modify the objects in place then you're better off with your current approach.

On another note, why is `Name` and `Address` represented as `int`? seems strange as usually it's represented as a `string`.

Comment: @Neo Right I see.

Comment: thanks a lot how can i achieve the same within `MyData<T>(List<T> listofCompany ){}` method because it is having generic list

Comment: @Neo well there is no way to access `Name` or `Address` without putting a constraint on `T` which you may or may not deem appropriate....

Comment: ok because while calling method MyData(listofCompany) doing this

Comment: you mean only runtime we can able to do it?

Comment: @Neo **at compile time** in order to access `Name` or `Address` from `T` within `List<T>` there must be a constraint on `T` otherwise `T` could literally be anything e.g. `StringBuilder`, `Person`, `Car` you name it.... anyway why are you making this method generic?

Comment: this method is used by all other list like depending upon condition i call this method and pass CustomerList , PersonList , OwnerList and so on...

Comment: For a "generic solution" (where generic here isn't ".NET Generics"), you could use reflection and a list of property names/types/values.  It's not very hard to do, but it's often not the best solution.